# What's Python's equivalent to C's read function?

Tags: python, c

C's `read`:

> The read() function shall attempt to read nbyte bytes from the file associated with the open file descriptor, fildes, into the buffer pointed to by buf.
>
> Upon  successful completion, these functions shall return a non-negative integer indicating the number of bytes **actually read**. Otherwise, the functions shall return −1 and set errno to indicate the error.

Python's `read`:

> Read at most n characters from stream.
>
> Read from underlying buffer until we have n characters or we **hit EOF**.
>       If n is negative or omitted, read until EOF.

Bold fonts are mine. Basically Python will insist on finding EOF if currrently available data is less than buffer size... How to make it simply return whatever is available?

Comment: It does return what's available, `file.read(1024)` will return `n` characters where `n` is the number of chars available up to 1024. Can you be clear with a reproducible example of what you need?

Comment: @RafaelBarros That is true only when reading from a non-blocking resource such as a regular file. When reading from a socket or pipe, C's `read()` will wait for only as long as it takes to have *some* data available, and then it will return the data. Python's `file.read` will, like C's `fread()`, attempt to return all requested data, unless encountering an error or EOF.

Comment: There is no `read` in the C language. What you are quoting is a manual of an API provided by your OS. Such APIs normally has bindings for C, but fortunately also for Python. You want to look at `posix.read` or `os.read`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "Python's `read`" I assume you mean the `read` method of `file` objects. That method is closer in spirit to C's `fread`: it implements buffering and it tries to satisfy the requested amount, unless that is impossible due to an IO error or end-of-file condition.

If you really need to call the `read()` function available in many C environments, you can call `os.read()` to invoke the underlying C function. The only difference is that it returns the data read as a byte string, and it raises an exception in the cases when the C function would return -1.

If you call `os.read()`, remember to give it the file descriptor obtained using the `fileno` method on file objects, or returned by functions in the `os` module such as `os.open`, `os.pipe`, etc. Also remember not to mix calls to `os.open()` and `file.open()`, since the latter does buffering and can cause later calls to `os.open()` not to return the buffered data.

Comment: That's it. Actually you just need to write `os.read` and I understand the rest. Not having enough sleep makes a guy pop out weird questions. Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, `os.read` returns a `bytes` (as it should) in Python 3. So I'll go with it.

Comment: @Cyker Thanks, I've now corrected it to say "byte string", referring to `str` (a byte string) in Python 2 and `bytes` in Python 3.